# What is a different expression/phrase/word for someone who lets others do their "dirty work" for them?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I am currently writing an essay on the movie *Paths of Glory* and how one General  (General Broulard) is more dislikable and villainous than the other. One facet of my argument addresses how he lets others do the dirty work for him - though he does not directly spill blood, he is responsible for a lot of strife, and he keeps his hands clean through manipulation and his status as a General. I know there is a better phrase to use than "lets others do his dirty work" but cannot think of it.

Comment: Maybe: *He has henchmen.* https://www.dictionary.com/browse/henchman

Comment: Yes, that's what generals do. It's called 'commanding'.

Comment: Just a note that this came up in English Language Learners but didn't get a very good reply https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54340/what-is-a-name-for-someone-who-doesnt-want-to-get-their-hands-dirty-has-their

Answer (score 1):

A leader of men who insists on making his underlings do all the dirty work (and then takes the credit for how well the work is done) is not a leader, but a tyrant.

A tyrant looks down on his people and considers them less worthy of respect than he is. A tyrant *demands* respect, but he doesn't *command* respect by being an example to those who follow him. Some synonyms for a tyrant include the following:

- dictator
- despot
- oppressor
- authoritarian
- autocrat
- bully
- martinet slave-driver
- control freak
- tormenter
- totalitarian
- monocrat

Answer (score 0):

*Delegator* might be a useful word but I can't think of one specific to villainy.

Answer (score 0):

*Overseer* might do well with its connections to slavery in the USA. *Kingpin* refers to the boss of criminal (dirty) organization.

Answer (score 0):

*Instigator* sometimes carries the implication of someone who is responsible for a criminal act, without doing it themselves.

The [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com) definition of Instigator carries this meaning.

> verb (used with object), in·sti·gat·ed, in·sti·gat·ing.
>   to cause by incitement; foment: *to instigate a quarrel.*
>   to urge, provoke, or incite to some action or course: *to instigate the people to revolt.*

You could also say that the General *Orchestrates* or *Masterminds* events, which again carry the suggestion of "hands off" manipulation.

Relevant synonyms for *Instigator* include *agitator*, *meddler*, *provocateur*.

Comment: This would be improved with some dictionary definitions for the selected words.

Comment: I've added one, thanks @KillingTime